# Hive installation fails on Hadoop 2.7.3 through amabari

Tags: python-2.7, hadoop, hive, ambari

I am trying to install hive on hadoop 2.7.2 with hdp 2.5. My ambari version is 2.4. Every other component is working fine (HDFS,YARN, MR2, ZOOKEEPER etc.).

When i am trying to install hive with new MySql database through ambari UI it give me following error for HCat client installation:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/common-services/HIVE/0.12.0.2.0/package/scripts/hcat_client.py", line 85, in <module>
    HCatClient().execute()   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/libraries/script/script.py", line 280, in execute
    method(env)   File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/common-services/HIVE/0.12.0.2.0/package/scripts/hcat_client.py", line 35, in install
    self.install_packages(env)   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/libraries/script/script.py", line 567, in install_packages
    retry_count=agent_stack_retry_count)   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/base.py", line 155, in __init__
    self.env.run()   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/environment.py", line 160, in run
    self.run_action(resource, action)   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/environment.py", line 124, in run_action
    provider_action()   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/providers/package/__init__.py", line 54, in action_install
    self.install_package(package_name, self.resource.use_repos, self.resource.skip_repos)   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/providers/package/yumrpm.py", line 49, in install_package
    self.checked_call_with_retries(cmd, sudo=True, logoutput=self.get_logoutput())   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/providers/package/__init__.py", line 83, in checked_call_with_retries
    return self._call_with_retries(cmd, is_checked=True, **kwargs)   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/providers/package/__init__.py", line 91, in _call_with_retries
    code, out = func(cmd, **kwargs)   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 71, in inner
    result = function(command, **kwargs)   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 93, in checked_call
    tries=tries, try_sleep=try_sleep)   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 141, in _call_wrapper
    result = _call(command, **kwargs_copy)   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 294, in _call
    raise Fail(err_msg) resource_management.core.exceptions.Fail: Execution of '/usr/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y install hive_2_5_0_0_1245' returned 1. Error unpacking rpm package hive_2_5_0_0_1245-1.2.1000.2.5.0.0-1245.el6.noarch error: unpacking of archive failed on file /usr/hdp/2.5.0.0-1245/hive/conf: cpio: rename failed - Is a directory
```

Comment: are you doing this with admin user or not ? if not then try with that. also try to download hive package rpm again may be its corrupted

Comment: Yes, I am doing this with admin user.Still not able to install. :( . I am able to install hive from command line.But I want to install from Ambari.